# Is there any way to divide server resources between users of Java application?

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, load-balancing

I wonder if there is any possibility to split the users of Java application running under Tomcat by server resources?

**Problem description**

We have an application written in Java and running under the control of Tomcat server. Sometimes users could possibly do some actions leading to 100% charge of server during a long period of time. That requires some limitation of server resources per user to disable him to make a server crash.

For a moment the only idea I've come up with is to containerize all the application in Docker and launch a separate resource-limited container for each user. It looks like missing an easier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you intend to split Server resources?
Memory is shared across the JVM and you cannot limit given memory for a certain Thread. Spawning a new process it the only way to further limit memory in an easy and maintainable way.

If you want to avoid that, you would probably have to rework your memory intensive method.